# How to check the type 'undefined' in the if instruction?

Tags: angular, typescript

Console show me:
true
undefined
In my opinion Console should show:
false
undefined
Because mytickets is equal undefined.

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.getMyTickets();

    if (this.mytickets !== null || this.mytickets !== undefined)  {
      this.showMyTickets = true;
    } else {
      this.showMyTickets = false;
    }
    console.log(this.showMyTickets);
    console.log(this.mytickets);

  }

  getMyTickets() {
    this.mtService.getAllMyTickets().subscribe(res => {
      this.mytickets = res;
    });
  }
```

Comment: The condition `(this.mytickets !== null || this.mytickets !== undefined)` is always `true` because the value cannot be `null` and `undefined` at the same time. Use `&&` instead of `||`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User @ConnorsFan already answered your question.

---

```
if (this.mytickets !== null || this.mytickets !== undefined)
```

should look like this instead:

```
if (this.mytickets !== null && this.mytickets !== undefined)
//                          ^^
```

---

A more JavaScript idiomatic way would be as simple as

```
if (this.mytickets)
```

because non-null, non-undefined objects are treated as `true` value in `if` boolean expressions.

You can read on [MDN about "truthy" in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy).

Comment: What if `this.mytickets` is a number and 0 is a valid value?

Comment: `0` will be interpreted as `false` as well.

If you need a _strict_ check against `null` and `undefined`, you have to use `===`/`!==`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `!!` (double negation) to check if this.mytickets is defined or not.

```
if(!!this.mytickets){this.showMyTickets = true;}
```

Double-negation turns a "truthy" or "falsy" value into a boolean value, `true` or `false`

Comment: When I use if (!!this.mytickets) always result is value true. this.mytickets is type of interface for build structure object mytickets.

Comment: ok. so that explains the problem. You should be checking for myTickets object that is received after `this.mtService.getAllMyTickets().subscribe(res => {
      this.mytickets = res;
    });`. find out if `res` is defined

Comment: The TypeScript compiler uses interfaces solely for type-checking purposes. You shouldn't be checking if your interface is defined

Comment: ok, when i use this code getMyTickets() {
    this.mtService.getAllMyTickets().subscribe(res => {
      this.mytickets = res;
      if (!!res) {
        this.showMyTickets = true;
      } else {
        this.showMyTickets = false;
      }
      console.log(this.showMyTickets);
      console.log(this.mytickets);
    });
  } my result in console is always true too